# Implementing On Click attribute in XML and pass a method Which takes view as parameter

Tags: android, function, kotlin, attributes, parameter-passing

I have created a variable  inside the data tag of my own custom type in XML file

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="gameViewModel"
            type="com.example.andriod.splock.screens.game.GameViewModel" />
</data>
```

The variable of this class has a method `choicemade(view : View)` which takes a  View as parameter

I am unable to pass  `it` as a reference for my image view

The following code displays  cannot find indentifier method

```
<imageView
  ...
android:onClick="@{() -> gameViewModel.choicemade(it)}"/>
```

How can I pass the reference for the Image View?

Comment: change with `android:onClick="@{(view) -> gameViewModel.choicemade(view)}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<ImageView
...
android:onClick="@{(view) -> gameViewModel.choicemade(view)}"/>
```